# Como percorrer um JSON dentro de outro JSON em Python?

Tags: python, json, urllib

Gostaria de saber como posso percorrer um *JSON* dentro de outro *JSON* em Python.

Nessa caso, tenho um arquivo que está no seguinte link:
https://sisu-api-pcr.apps.mec.gov.br/api/v1/oferta/instituicao/570

E estou utilizando a biblioteca *urllib.request* para ler o meu arquivo *main.py* da seguinte maneira:

```
import urllib.request  #importando biblioteca urllib.request
import json #importando biblioteca json

url = 'https://sisu-api-pcr.apps.mec.gov.br/api/v1/oferta/instituicao/570' #atribuindo valor link a variável url
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url+str()).read() #Abrindo e lendo URL - Atribuindo valor a variável resposta
resp = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8')) #Codificando URL para codificação UTF-8

for x in resp:  #Percorrendo toda variável resp
   print(x['co_oferta']+' - '+x['no_curso']) #Imprimindo somente os campos necessários
   print("") #Imprimindo linha em branco
```

---

No saída do terminal, ele me retorna um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Documents\Projetos\Python\python-json-ufs\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(x['co_ies']+' - '+x['no_ies']) #Imprimindo somente os campos necess�rios
TypeError: string indices must be integers

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.956 seconds
```

Percebi que o arquivo inicia-se com:

```
{
  "search_rule":"UFRN - UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO RIO GRANDE DO NORTE",
  "0":{
        "co_oferta":"184760",
        "co_termo_adesao":"4316",
         .
         .
         .
         .
```

Como fosse um arquivo *JSON* dentro de outro.

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar a ler corretamente esse arquivo.

Comment: Segue o link do teste funcionando https://replit.com/join/llrgypqq-lucasandradetho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma maneira única de iterar por uma estrutura de dados JSON, mas essa estrutura é um dicionário composto por dicionários aninhados então após fazer a análise do JSON com [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/json.html#json.loads) itere pelo itens usando [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) desempacotando em `k` e `v`, onde `k` é a chave no dicionário principal e `v` é o valor ou dicionário aninhado.

> Como [comentado pelo autor da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/502967/como-percorrer-um-json-dentro-de-outro-json-em-python/502987?noredirect=1#comment929438_502987) as chaves de interesse são *co_oferta* e *no_curso*.

```
import json
import urllib.request

#Carrega um JSON
url = 'https://sisu-api-pcr.apps.mec.gov.br/api/v1/oferta/instituicao/570'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
  resp = response.read()

#Faz a análise desse JSON.
resp = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8'))

#Itera por todos os itens do dicionário principal....
for k, v in resp.items():
  #...se a 'co_oferta' está contida no dicionário aninhado...
  if 'co_oferta' in v:
    print(v['co_oferta'], end=" ")         #...se sim, imprime seu valor.
  else:
    print("XXX")                        #...se não, imprime `XXX`
  #...se a 'no_curso' está contida no dicionário aninhado...
  if 'no_curso' in v:
    print(v['no_curso'])                  #...se sim, imprime seu valor.
  else:
    print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX ") #...se não, imprime `XXX.......`
  print()
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repli.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/GrowingCompetentProcedurallanguage#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Utiliza-se para esse código acima as seguintes chaves: co_oferta e no_curso

Answer (score 1):

Conforme acima segue todo o código:

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'https://sisu-api-pcr.apps.mec.gov.br/api/v1/oferta/instituicoes'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
resp = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8'))



for i, x in enumerate(resp):
    print(x['co_ies']+" -  "+x['no_ies'])
```

**saída:**

> 21503 -  COLÉGIO PEDRO II
> 593 -  CENTRO FEDERAL DE EDUCAÇÃO TECNOLÓGICA CELSO SUCKOW DA FONSECA
> 26 -  ESCOLA NACIONAL DE CIÊNCIAS ESTATÍSTICAS
> 3223 -  ESCOLA SUPERIOR DE CIÊNCIAS DA SAÚDE
> 12 -  UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO RIO GRANDE
> 1120 -  INSTITUTO FEDERAL DE EDUCAÇÃO, CIÊNCIA E TECNOLOGIA FLUMINENSE
> 1303 -  INSTITUTO FEDERAL DE EDUCAÇÃO, CIÊNCIA E TECNOLOGIA GOIANO...

com a url **'https://sisu-api-pcr.apps.mec.gov.br/api/v1/oferta/instituicao/570'**

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'https://sisu-api-pcr.apps.mec.gov.br/api/v1/oferta/instituicao/570'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
resp = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8'))

print(json.dumps(resp['search_rule']))

for i in range(len(resp['search_rule']) - 48):
    print("=============")
    print((resp[str(i)]['no_curso']))
```

esta acima veja que as chaves são strings

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou tranquilo.

Comment: coloquei o range para len(resp['search_rule']) - 48 apenas para nao listar tudo e encher meu terminal , pois se der um ```len(resp['search_rule'])``` vai ver que ele tem tamanho 50 .

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia, o erro está em tentar percorrer os índices da lista colocando texto no campo: **print(x['co_ies']+**. resp é uma lista de json. A solução seria utilizar enumerate:

```
for i, x in enumerate(resp):
    print(x['co_ies']+ " - " + x['no_ies'])
```

Comment: Tentei a sua solução amigo, e me retornou o seguinte erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Documents\Projetos\Python\python-json-ufs\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(x['co_ies']+ " - " + x['no_ies'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.846 seconds

Comment: veja que somente da certo se fizer antes resp = json.loads(resp.decode("utf-8") , senão dará este erro daí, aqui fiz e funcionou

Comment: **veja como ficou : ** ```>>> for i,x in enumerate(resp):
...     print(x['co_ies'] + ' - ' + x['no_ies'])
... 
21503 - COLÉGIO PEDRO II
593 - CENTRO FEDERAL DE EDUCAÇÃO TECNOLÓGICA CELSO SUCKOW DA FONSECA
26 - ESCOLA NACIONAL DE CIÊNCIAS ESTATÍSTICAS
3223 - ESCOLA SUPERIOR DE CIÊNCIAS DA SAÚDE
12 - UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO RIO GRANDE ```

Comment: ok, vou postar, o codigo completo, desculpa ter enviado somente o trecho ;)